# Get values of multiple toggle buttons into JavaScript array object

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, angular8

I've a list which is iterated using *ngFor to a toggle button. I need to get the values of all the true/false buttons into JavaScript array objects.

[image]

This is the input given.

```
this.list = {
  "name":"John",
  "age":30,
  "cars": [
    { "name":"Ford", "models":1},
    { "name":"BMW", "models":2},
    { "name":"Fiat", "models":3 }
  ]
 }
```

HTML for toggle buttons

```
    <div *ngFor = "let x of list.cars;">
    {{x.name}}
    <toggle-button [config]="config" (onStateChange)="onStateChanged1($event, x.name)">
    </toggle-button>
    <toggle-button [config]="config" (onStateChange)="onStateChanged2($event, x.name)">
    </toggle-button>
    <toggle-button [config]="config" (onStateChange)="onStateChanged3($event, x.name)">
    </toggle-button>
    <toggle-button [config]="config" (onStateChange)="onStateChanged4($event, x.name)">
    </toggle-button>
    </div>
```

Toggle button functions

```
      public onStateChanged1(value: boolean, name) {
        this.value1 = value;
        this.name1 = name;
        console.log(this.value1)
      }
        public onStateChanged2(value: boolean,name) {
        this.value2 = value;
         this.name1 = name;
      }  public onStateChanged3(value: boolean,name) {
        this.value3 = value;
         this.name1 = name;
      }  public onStateChanged4(value: boolean,name) {
        this.value4 = value;
         this.name1 = name;
      }
```

Required Output

```
[{
name: ford,
code1:  true,
code2:  false, 
code3:  false,  
code4:  false, 
  },
   {
name: BMW,
code1:  true,
code2:  false, 
code3:  false,  
code4:  false, 
  },
  {
name: Fiat,
code1:  true,
code2:  false, 
code3:  false,  
code4:  false, 
  }]
```

Comment: When do you need to get the values?

Comment: on your onStateChange1,2,3,4 you always change 'this.name1', is it a mistake?

Comment: `code1`, `code2`, `code3`... `name1`, `name2`, `name3`.... `value1`, `value2`, `value3`. Please use arrays and data structures: `codes: [true, false, false, false]` and access with `codes[0]`, etc.

Comment: @andre on clicking the test button, I need the values of the selected toggle.buttons which are shown in the top image. The required output pattern is given in the bottom of the question.